# InitContainer consume config.template from container image in kubernetes

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

**Summary:**
I want to be able to get config.template files in **InitContainer** from **Container**.

**The existing state:**
There are template configuration files, that rarely change and contains **PlaceHolders**, stored inside the image of the **container**.
When we create the container in the kubernetes there is a script stored also in the image that run and replace all the PlaceHolders with the real values and then start the service.

**The desired state:**
Having a Init-Container that built from **generic** image with generic code that need to get as arguments only the directories of the template files (as array of directories) and when it run it take all the template files from the container's image (throw **volume**), replace the PlaceHolders with the real value and create a final configuration files in a volume that shared with the container.
That way the Init-Container do the preparations and when it done the Container need to *start immediately with the prepared configuration files*.
also, the same image of the Init-Container can be used in pods with other containers.

**The Problem:**
The Init-Container is start first and the volume that map to the Container image and supposed to contain the config.template files is **still empty** when the Init-Container is running.

**My Questions:**
- Is there an easy and good way to get those config.template files from the container image from the Init-Container before the container in running?
- Is there a better solution for this problem to get the same or similar result?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no a way to access the files from container in pod into [`init-containers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/). The `volume` that is shared between your `init-container` and the container of pod is empty because the container of pod is [not started until all init-containers successfully exit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#detailed-behavior)(with exit code `0`).

So the way I suggest you do stuff is create a [`configMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/) with the `templates` you want. [Mount this `configMap`](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-volumes) inside the `init-container`. And inside the `init-container` do the replacement of place holder values in `template` coming from `configMap` and dump it into the `volume` you have shared between container of pod and the `init-container` of the pod.

Now this helps you change the config as you want, all you need to do is update the `configMap` resource. Also the code to replace the place holder values can change and all you need to do is build the image for `init-container`. Also this helps you keep the init-container image generic as you want.

With this de-coupling your source code container remains independent of change in the config.

Also this `init-container` and `configMap` gets used into other pods as you like it.

Comment: Tnx for the answer but i want the templates will remain in the Container image.